# cannot be cast to java.lang.Class

Tags: java

I'm trying to get a list of objects type from my class **objectCollection** using generic type. However, I had an error saying

> myClass cannot be cast to java.lang.Class

I thought I was using generic Class correctly. How do I fix this?

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <T> ArrayList<T> getGameObj(ArrayList <T> obj) {
    Class <T> objType = null; 
    while (objectIterator.hasNext()) {
        objType = (Class<T>) objectIterator.getNext();  /* Error here */
        if (objectIterator.getCurrent().getClass().isAssignableFrom(objType.getClass())) 
            obj.add( (T) objectIterator.getCurrent());

    }
    return obj;
}
```

Comment: What is `objectIterator`? Don't add `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`. And under what circumstance would your `if` check fail? Since you appear to be trying to test if the current element type is assignable from itself.

Comment: it's just something to store different objects type like a List

Comment: Is `objectIterator` a list of classes, or a list of objects, or a list of something else?  How do you define it?  (Please show us the definition.)

Comment: try objectIterator.next();

Comment: It's not possible to answer this without seeing the declaration of `objectIterator`, but I strongly suspect that the indicated line is just supposed to read EITHER `objType = (T) objectIterator.getNext();` OR `objType = (T) objectIterator.next();`

Answer (score 1):

**Option1:**
Change

```
objType = (Class<T>) objectIterator.getNext();  /* Error here */
```

to

```
 objType = (Class<T>) objectIterator.next();
```

**Option2:**
Alternatively, you can store the Type and Class into a HashMap
`HashMap<Class, Type>` . and add the entries to this hashmap when the objects are defined/before the iterator `objectIterator` is created. And then use the hashmap to get the Type from the class of objectIterator.next()

Comment: Given what the error message is, I think this is _highly unlikely_ to be the correct solution.

Comment: Option 2 in the answer may help